# rsync ~/.mozilla directory

Tags: rsync, firefox

I'd like to `rsync` my `Firefox` profiles and back them up.

Is it sufficient to `rsync` `~/.mozilla` directory? Or should I be even more specific
and backup only certain crucial files and directories?
Is it needed to close `Firefox` when running `rsync` or is it OK to have it opened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sufficient to backup ~/.mozilla. It'd be best to do it while FF is not running, but probably okay to do it when you aren't actively using it, since most of the file changing with be when you click on new links.

Comment: I have this error `rsync: symlink "/media/extdevice/rsync_backups/blablabla.default-release/lock" -> "127.0.1.1:+3956" failed: Operation not permitted (1)` Can I supress this error? I have `vfat` filesystem on the flash drive.

Comment: my `rsync` command: `sudo rsync -avh --delete --no-o --no-g --modify-window=1 /home/xralf/.mozilla/firefox/blablabla.default-release /media/extdevice/rsync_backups/`

Comment: Maybe you need to add --no-l?

Comment: I can't find it in man page.

Comment: Like --no-o and --no-g to not preserve owner and group, --no-l says to not try to create symlinks.

Comment: OK, I tried it and it does not copy those files. Do I need those symbolic links which are in `.mozilla/firefox/blablabla.default-release` directory to restore securely my backup?

Comment: That's tricky, but I would assume so. To that end, I suggest you back them up to a device formatted with the same filesystem as what you are using for your home directory.

Comment: Or maybe use tar.

Comment: Where are the links pointing? Try `find ~/.mozilla -type l -exec ls -l {} +` to see the links and where they point. All I see there is a lockfile that links to a socket on localhost, so I sort of presume that's handled on the fly. Then again the best way to test would be to transfer a profile and see.

I also second the suggestion to use the same filesystem format for your backups, there's plenty of features that are only available on some filesystems and not others.